# How to send QImage to Qt3D Entity from C++ to QML for using it as texture?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qt3d

I need to change the texture of a plane in a 3D scene. In the BackEnd class in C++ I make a new QImage for setting it on a texture. I want to send it as a signal to my QML and there assign it to the planes material property.

But it looks like TextureMaterial etc. can only use a URL path to a texture file. I cant't save my Images to my hard drive to use them as a URL path. It will be too long. I need to change my texture 20+ times in a second and there are other things which this program should to do in the same time.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my implementation of a [background image in Qt3D](https://github.com/florianblume/Qt3D-BackgroundImage).

The way I achieved what you are looking for is by using the classes `QTextureMaterial`, `QTexture2D` and `QPaintedTextureImage`. I had to flip the image before drawing it that's why I subclassed `QPaintedTextureImage` but this might also just be what you need. Instead of loading the texture from disk, like I did, you could set the `QImage` on your subclass as an attribute. You only need to make the C++ class available to QML and set it on your plane (maybe you could even use `PaintedTextureImage` directly and write the image painting in their JavaScript-style language).

You can add your `QPaintedTextureIage` to the `QTexture2D` and then set the result as the texture on the `QTextureMaterial`. I'm not sure if this yields the best performance, though.

You could also try to follow [these steps](https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/cKrvD9nr/synchronous-update-of-qt3d-texture-data) but they seem to be a bit more involved. This would mean you have to implement your own version of `QAbstractTextureImage` and return the appropriate `QTextureImageDataGeneratorPtr`. You can checkout the [sources](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/5.12/src/render) to gain a better understanding.